# SpringBoot is not picking Application.properties from src/main/resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, mybatis

I'm using SpringBoot 3.x and myBatis. When I start my application, tomcat is not picking my application properties instead it is taking the default testDB url and gives me the error as mentioned in the screenshot below[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSypS.png)

My application properties is under src/main/resources and after maven build is successful it is present under target/classes. I have set the spring.profile.active=local in the application properties.

In the Run Configuration,
I tired two methods to tell springboot to load my application properties

1. Tried adding the VM options as -Dspring.config.location=application.properties and set the active to "local" but didnt work and gives out the same error as shown in the screenshot
2. I tried adding program arguments as --spring-config-location=application.properties and set the active to "local", this didnt work too and gives out the same error as shown in the screenshot

Comment: there are couple of ways to solve it

Comment: PropertySource can be good solution if you have custom application properties file

Comment: Also resource folder is extracted outside and it will be near your class files

Comment: That's the default. You don't need to specify the path. If you're specifying a profile of `local`, any properties for that profile will override properties defined in `application.properties`. If the properties you're trying to use should trigger for the `local` profile, name your file `application-local.properties`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Tried changing the application.properties to application-local.properties but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

what IDE are you using ?

You might need to mark the resourse folder as your Resource root

Check for other configurations: Make sure there are no conflicting configurations in your application, such as other property sources that might be overriding the values specified in application.properties.

VM Options or Program Arguments: The correct option to specify the location of the application properties file is -Dspring.config.location=classpath:application.properties for VM options and --spring.config.location=classpath:application.properties for program arguments. Make sure you are using the correct syntax and that the path to the properties file is correct.

Comment: I'm using Intellij IDE and yes it is marked as resources root. For the VM options, do I have to specify path like this "-Dspring.config.location=classpath:H:/project/src/main/resource/application.properties" ?

Comment: Also dont give absolute path

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez i tired giving relative path as well, it didnt work